# Grep between two patterns in code

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a pattern that looks something like this .

```
var a ; 
var b;

var obj = {
aa : 'This is what I want'
};
```

I want the text between `aa : '` and `'};`

There might be multiple occurrences of this, but I would like to have the first one.

I have tried awk , grep and sed. But none of them gave me the perfect result, but spit out entire code.

What I have tried till now :

```
grep -Po "aa : \K.*(?= \'};)"
sed -e 's/aa :\(.*\)\n};/\1/'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F"'" -v RS=";" '/\naa/{print $2;exit}'
```

Comment: It does not work. Please add a line between `aa : 'This is what I want'` and `;}` and try again

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN {Found = 0;} /^aa :/{Found = 1; } /^};/{Found = 0;} {if(Found) {print $0;}}'
```

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: I'm getting: `aa : 'This is what I want'};`

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -oP` you can use match reset `\K`:

```
grep -oP "\baa\s*:\s*'\K[^']+" file

This is what I want
```

Answer (score 0):

If I really bend it in AWK:

```
BEGIN {
    RS="- -it is not the spoon that bends, it is only yourself"
    FS="(aa : '|'};)"
}
{
    print $2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS="aa[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*'[^']*'[[:space:]]*}[[:space:]]*;" -F"'" '{$0=RT; print $2; exit}' file
This is what I want
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a another solution, using `sed`:

```
echo $'var obj = {\naa: \'This is what I want\'\n};
var obj2 = {\naa: \'Unwanted\'\n};' | \
sed -ne $'/aa:/ {N;s/aa: \'\\(.*\\)\'\\n.*/\\1/;T;p;q}'
```

`T;p;q` prints the replacement on the first match and quits, and continues with next line otherwise.